# How to read OData association for multiple records

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5, northwind

Let's take the [Northwind](http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc) odata service as an example. To get all the products of a supplier '1' I would use the following [URL](http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Suppliers(1)/Products) and in SAPUI5 it equals to: `oModel.read("/Suppliers(1)/Products");`

But what if I have 10 different suppliers and would like to get all products belonging to these suppliers. What is the correct way to do that? Should I loop at `oModel.read("/Suppliers(X)/Products");` where X is the supplier number? Or should I use filters on the Products entity set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter Suppliers and use the $expand query attribute to include the corresponding Products into the result. This [URL](http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Suppliers?$filter=(SupplierID%20le%205)&$expand=Products) will return Suppliers with an ID less than 5 and their Products. As a Supplier might have a lot of products it may be better to do it the other way around, filter Products and expand the corresponding Supplier. This [URL](http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$filter=(Supplier/SupplierID%20le%205)%20and%20(ProductID%20le%205)&$expand=Supplier) will return Products whose ID and Supplier ID are less than 5. In a real world scenario you would apply different filters, but the idea should be clear.